# Wikipedia Spam Filter Notice

Tags: spam-prevention, google-chrome, wikipedia, google-chrome-extensions

I've been an occasional Wikipedia editor and user for many years.  Twice recently when I tried to make a minor page edit, I received the following error:  "Spam filter notice"

Your edit was not saved because it contains a new external link to a site registered on Wikipedia's blacklist."

However, (of course) I added no spam links and none are visible in the claimed highlighted text.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This makes no sense at all, but somehow the Chrome LastPass extension is triggering the spam filter.  I tested this by opening an incognito window and performing the identical edit, which succeeded.

After that, I disabled all plugins and enabled them until I found the culprit.  I guess I'll have to temporarily disable LastPass whenever I edit Wikipedia for the time being.